# Need help on solving this Arrays problem using java

Tags: arrays, integer, randomized-algorithm

Make an array of integer (score) with 10 members. Randomize the
content with value between 0-100. For each of the member of array,
visualize the value using “-” for each ten. For example: score[0] = 55 will be visualized as “-----" (Using Java).

```
public class w9lab1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      double[] temperature = new double[7];
      for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
           temperature[i] = Math.random()*100;
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
           System.out.println(temperature[i]);
      }
     
      double totalTemperature = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < 7 ; i++) {
            totalTemperature += temperature[i];
      }
      double maxTemperature = temperature[0];
      for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++){
            if (temperature[i] > maxTemperature){
            maxTemperature = temperature[i];
        }
      }
        System.out.println("Temperatur maximum adalah " + maxTemperature);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi&Welcome! What is the question/problem?  (Why is it `double []` and not "array of integer", why `7` and not `10` ...what if tutor tomorrow says: `11` (or `n`..)? How is total&max temperature related? (Why 4 loops instead of 1?) ..and where is "visualization"?) ..the "rest" looks ok!:)

Comment: I think I put the wrong coding in the question

Comment: You can [edit],np :)

Comment: ..what "looks ok" (matching the task description) , was: `Math.random()*100;` (in a loop)

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class w9lab1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int[] score = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {
            score[i] = random.nextInt(101);
            for (int n = 1; n <= score[i] / 10; n++)
                System.out.print('-');
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(score));
    }
}
```